# Why doesn't my Jasmine test execute application code inside a for loop?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, for-loop, jasmine

Say I have a simple function with a `for` statement:

```
public addIcons(icons): void {
    for (let icon of icons) {
        this.iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(icon['name'], icon['path']);
    }
}
```

If I attempt to spy on `iconRegistry.addSvgIcon`, the test fails. If I modify the app to call `addSvgIcon` outside the `for` loop, it passes.

```
it('should add icons to the registry', inject([IconService, MdIconRegistry], (
  service: IconService, 
  iconRegistry: MdIconRegistry) => {
    spyOn(iconRegistry, 'addSvgIcon');
    service.addIcons({ 'name': 'blah', 'path': 'blech' });
    expect(iconRegistry.addSvgIcon).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Console logs indicate that the `addIcons` function is being called, but the `for` statement isn't being entered. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert with Typescript, but you are passing an object as a parameter to `addIcons`, which expects an array.

Change this line:

```
service.addIcons({ 'name': 'blah', 'path': 'blech' });
```

to this:

```
service.addIcons([{ 'name': 'blah', 'path': 'blech' }]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Voting to close as a typo. We'll let the community decide.